# Error trying to get PHP array to JSON after adding headers (for AJAX)

Tags: php, json, ajax

I am trying to get users' data (hypothetical) from mySQL database, store them in an array, convert the array to json to be able to use it in AJAX requests in Javascript.

The code works, but when I add:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *");
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

at the top of the index.php, the browser gives me the error:

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 5 column 1 of the JSON data
```

I still haven't any .js file btw, I'm just trying to get it ready for ajax,
and I know the first two headers make the json accessible from the client,
and the last header tells it is in json format.

Here is the code; all the files are in one folder;
**index.php**

```
<?php 
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *");
header('Content-Type: application/json');

require 'config.php';

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "GET") {
    if(isset($_GET['request'])) {
            if($_GET['request'] == "user" && isset($_GET['name'])) {
                $test = new TestClass($_GET['name']);
                $detail = $test->get_detail();
                echo json_encode($detail);
        } 
        
        else if($_GET['request'] == "users") {
              $users = TestClass::get_users();
            echo json_encode($users);
        }
        } 
} ?>
```

**config.php**

```
<?php
$dbhost="localhost";
$dbname="ajax";
$dbuser="root";
$dbpassword="";

require 'test.class.php'; ?>
```

**test.class.php**

```
<?php
    class TestClass {
            private $name;
            function __construct($name) {
                    $this->name = $name; 
                }
          public function get_detail() {
                try {
            $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=".$GLOBALS['dbhost'].";dbname=".$GLOBALS['dbname'], $GLOBALS['dbuser'], $GLOBALS['dbpassword']);
            $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users where username = ?");
            $stmt->execute([$this->name]);
            $res = $stmt->fetch();
            return array(
                                "ID" => $res['ID'],
                                "username" => $res['username'],
                                "email" => $res['email'],
                                "password" => $res['password'],
            );

            }catch(PDOException $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
                return array();
                    }
                }
                public static function get_users() {
                    try{ 
                          $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=".$GLOBALS['dbhost'].";dbname=".$GLOBALS['dbname'], $GLOBALS['dbuser'], $GLOBALS['dbpassword']);
            $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users");
            $stmt->execute([]);
            $array = array();
            while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                                    array_push($array, array(
                                        "ID" => $row['ID'],
                                        "username" => $row['username'],
                                        "email" => $row['email'],
                                        "password" => $row['password'],
                                    ));
                                }
                            return $array;
                        } catch(PDOException $e) {
                                return array();
                            }
                    
                    }
        
        }?>
```

How i said I still don't have any JavaScript file. I am expecting to see the string of the Array in JSON format by going to: localhost/folder/index.php?request=users
From Firefox

info:
-server: XAMPP for Linux 8.1.10 (so, LAMPP);
-os: Ubuntu server 22.04.1 LTS x86_64, Kernel: 5.15.0-52-generic
-browser:  Firefox Browser 106.0.1 (via snap)

Thank you, I tried to google this, but nothing was clear to me.

**UPDATE**

I was following a tutorial, and whith the above code,
but without the three headers,
this was the output:

[image: IMG1-before]

But from what I understood, I also have to add the three headers to make it accessible from js.
after adding them, here's the output:

[image: IMG2-after]

I was expecting to see the data like in the first image.

Comment: It's really bad practise to use `$_GLOBALS` in general, and especially for sensitive Database connection details. Consider using a public function to import connection details without making the variable data available to *everything*.

Comment: Please edit your question and show us your Javascript/AJAX.

Comment: Which line is line 5 of your AJAX response?

Comment: How i said I still don't have any JavaScript file. I am expecting to see the string of the Array in JSON format by going to: localhost/folder/index.php?request=users

Comment: so you need to view the source of the webpage and tell us what that source data is? ie the data will be something from `$user` or `$details` so what do your PHP Error Logs tell you? I think you should do some reading up and follow some AJAX / JSON examples as currently it looks like you're running in the dark at the moment...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this, for some reason, which I still don't know,
when I changed the index.php to another structure
using the switch statement to manage the requests, the output was fine.

```
<?php 
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *");
header('Content-Type: application/json');

require 'config.php';

if(isset($_GET['request'])) {
    
    switch($_GET['request']) {
        
        case "user":
            $test = new TestClass($_GET['name']);
            $detail = $test->get_detail();
            echo json_encode($detail);
        break;
        
        case "users":
            $users = TestClass::get_users();
            echo json_encode($users);
        break;
        
        }
        
    }?>
```

[image]

Maybe someone can explain why this happened.

Comment: why is `get_users` a static function?! I would expect you should always create the class `new ...` and then simply call `get_details()` / `get_users()` based on your switch statement.